# Django view with column referenced as foreign from another table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have models that were created from a MySQL database using inspectdb and migrating what was found.

Right now I am trying to create a view for an html page. However, when I run the loop which is containing the returned values from the view I get this sort of response:

```
Customers object
331

total owed: 0.00
order date: Nov. 26, 2019, 10:10 p.m.
shipped: y
```

The 'Customers object' is a foreign key on the 'Orders' table referencing the 'Customers' table. I want it to include the 'customerid' column, but I guess in Django there must be some operation in the view to link these two columns, otherwise it appears this way.

The loop is run in the html page this way:

```
       {% block content %}
            <div class="row">
                {% for order in orders %}
                    <div class="col-4" >
                        <br>  
                        <p><strong> {{ order.customerid }} <br>  {{ order.orderid }} <br>  </strong> <br> 
                            total owed: {{ order.total }} <br> order date: {{ order.entrydate }} 
                            <br> shipped: {{ order.shipped }}
                    </div>   
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endblock content %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^orders/$', views.orders, name='orders'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Orders, Customers
# Create your views here.

def orders(request):
    orders = Orders.objects.all()
    context = {'orders': orders}
    return render(request,'albums/orders.html', context)
```

models.py with the referenced tables:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    customerid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    streetadd = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'customers'

class Orders(models.Model):
    orderid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    entrydate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    shipped = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    customerid = models.ForeignKey(Customers, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='customerid', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'orders'
```

It seems like a relatively easy fix that needs to go into the views 'orders' function, but the solutions I have tried weren't working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your Django version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the name of your foreignKey is `customerid` and you have same `field` in `Customer` model. 
So in order to render `Customer id` you would need to do:

```
{{ order.customerid.customerid }}
```

But your structure is not very good in general. it's better to have it like:

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='customerid', blank=True, null=True)
    ....
class Customers(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

If you change it in that way you can access it as:

```
{{ order.customer.id }}
```